# Keil C51 tools integrated into Qt Creator

Tags: qt-creator, keil

I like the Qt Creator development environment and now need to compile some C code using the Keil C51 compiler/tools.

Is it possible to use the Qt Creator IDE with Keil C51 tools?  Can someone describe in detail how to set that up?

OR - is than another 8052 chip compiler that can be integrated with Qt Creator?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm, that I'm able to use QT with C51.

### Environment

I use QT as Editor. 
And Keil C51 as compiler. I write a program in a pure C (not C++) for the STC microcontroller.

### TLDR

I use the Windows Batch file to compile all `*.c` files in the working directory and then link it together into a one hex file. Then I setup the QT (Projects -> Build Settings -> Build Steps -> Custom) to use this Batch during a building stage (don't forget to setup the working directory correctly).

### How to get a needed Batch file

#### Simple way

Keil can generate a batch for the particular project (see Project->Options for Target->Output->Create Batch File). Then use this file in the QT as described above.

The main flaw of this way is - when you change the project configs or add a new file to the project, you need to regenerate a Batch from the Keil.

#### Better way

Using generated Batch from Keil, I write my own Bath, that doesn't have the flaws, described above.

#### Even better way

I guess using a Makefile is better for this than Batch, as it gives QT more control and info about the errors during the compilation. But I dont't have an "on-shelf" example right now.

### Batch file description

In a nutshell, this Batch:

1. Setups the settings and directories
2. Calls compiler for every `*.c` file in the working dir
3. Builds `*.obj` list and call linker to obtain a firmware image in a binary format
4. Converts the obtained imge into a HEX format

The listing:

```
REM "Folders"
SET C51FLDR=d:\Keil\C51
SET OUTFLDR=.\Objects
SET LSTFLDR=.\Listings
SET HEXNAME=PREP_FIRMWARE

SET C51INC=%C51FLDR%\Inc;%C51FLDR%\Inc\STC
SET C51LIB=%C51FLDR%\Lib

REM "Variables"
SET C51EXE=%C51FLDR%\BIN\C51.EXE
SET C51LNK=%C51FLDR%\BIN\BL51.EXE
SET C51HEX=%C51FLDR%\BIN\OH51.EXE
set OBJLIST=

REM "Defines"
SET CPU_TYPE=STC15W408S
SET CPU_VENDOR=STC
SET UV2_TARGET=Target 1
SET CPU_XTAL=0x02160EC0
SET SETTINGS="COMPACT ROM(COMPACT) OPTIMIZE (9,SIZE) BROWSE DEBUG OBJECTEXTEND LISTINCLUDE SYMBOLS TABS (2)"


echo ===================== Compile =====================
for %%f in (*.c) do (
echo %errorlevel%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
%C51EXE% %%f  %SETTINGS% "PRINT(%LSTFLDR%\%%~nf.lst) OBJECT(%OUTFLDR%\%%~nf.obj)"
if !errorlevel! neq 0 exit /b !errorlevel!
)

echo ===================== Link =====================
call :obj_list
echo %OBJLIST%
%C51LNK%  %OBJLIST% TO "%OUTFLDR%\%HEXNAME%" PRINT("%LSTFLDR%\%HEXNAME%.m51") RAMSIZE(256) 
echo %errorlevel%
if %errorlevel% GTR 1 exit /b %errorlevel%

echo ===================== Hex =====================
%C51HEX% "%OUTFLDR%\%HEXNAME%" 
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%

echo ==========================================
echo Build Success
echo ==========================================
goto :eof

:obj_list
for %%f in (.\Objects\*.obj) DO call :concat %%f
set OBJLIST=%OBJLIST:~0,-1%
goto :eof

:concat
set OBJLIST=%OBJLIST%"%1",
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, it is possible to use QtCreator with Qbs (since 1.15). Also, it is possible to use VSCode with the Qbs extension.